# Workflow when you only have FTP access?

Tags: deployment, workflow

I'm building a simple low traffic website in Craft for a customer whose web server only allows access over ftp. How would you have done the work in practical terms? Building the site locally and then copy everything manually over FTP when done?

Is it for this kind of websites completely wrong to make minor adjustments directly on the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I absolutely agree with "build locally and then upload it".

[Deploybot](https://deploybot.com/) can deploy with ftp, and makes it quite painless to keep local and remote and git repo all in sync.

I make debugging sorts of changes directly on the server (tweak the config, tweak .htaccess, that sort of thing), but any change I want to keep I make sure to get into git.

Comment: We also use Deploybot. And we use bitbucket with 2 branches.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to go is build it locally then upload it.

After the initial upload, if you use a smart FTP client like [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit) you can sync both version to update your local version before making local changes then re-sync to upload them.

Editing online can be done but for me it is crucial that you always have a local backup just in case something happens, so even if I do edit online I then sync my changes.

PS. To keep both version running without changes you’ll have to take advantage of [Craft multi environment configs](https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs).

Comment: Sublime Text with Sublime SFTP works well for me working on the server for minor stuff. You can set it to upload when a file is saved, meaning it's saved locally first, then uploaded so you've always got the latest files local ready for git.